# Error using java nio

Tags: java, eclipse, java-7, nio

I am using jdk 7. I want to use nio package in my program but when I am trying to import java.nio.file.* , I am getting a error that java.nio.file package does not exist !

Comment: I checked my java folder it has jdk1.7.0 folder

Comment: Nevertheless you aren't using Java 7. Check your configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I expect that your Eclipse project is configured to build against an older Java profile.

If you are using Maven then you need to set the required Java version [in the POM file](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html).

Otherwise, [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2540730/139985) gives instructions for setting a project's target Java version.

---

> I am trying to compile using command prompt ,but still getting the same errors !!

In that case, either you are compiling with a `javac` from an older JDK (see what `javac -version` tells you!!) or it is a POM file issue.

Comment: I am trying to compile using command prompt ,but still getting the same errors !!

Comment: checked javac -version it is 1.7.0

Comment: @alexandre1985 - Did you read the answer?  Did you try the things it suggested?

Comment: @alexandre1985 - well this question is about eclipse,  If you have a question about some other IDE, you should keep searching ... or ask a new Question.