# while opening eclipse getting error

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder

I have installed flash builder plugin and i choose eclipse which i have.

While opening Falsh builder plugin with eclipse, getting error and showed a screen shot of the error message.

[image: http://img856.imageshack.us/img856/5366/chpp.png]

But if i open only eclipse it is working fine and no errors..
Can i know the reason and required any changes in eclipse or flash builder?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm reading the log correctly, but it looks like your Eclipse Helios install is a 64-bit version, and the Flash Builder plug-in is 32-bit.  Can you verify or refute this?  I know that trying to run a mismatched set will give you errors, but I don't know which ones.

Answer (score 0):

> Java was started but returned exit code=13

error is caused when you are attempting to start Eclipse using the wrong version of the Java Virtual Machine (JVM).

Your eclipse.ini file contains a java version which is different from the one installed/set on your machine.

Here are some recommendations to correct this error:

http://www.ehow.com/how_4784069_terminated-exit-code-error-eclipse.html

Comment: i have changed java version to 1.6 which is installed in my system . but still same issue is persist.

Answer (score 0):

Check your java version with command : java -version

And then compare it with the version of java shown in your error message of eclipse.

Maybe the version of of java that your eclipse support will be different from the installed java on your system.

Comment: I had installed java 1.6 version. In eclipse it is showing as 1.5 version. now where can to add in eclipse configuration.

Comment: Open the `eclipse.ini` and see the parameter `Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6`. `1.6`  is mine. Set what ever you want  to set.

Comment: @suresh:- i have tried the same but doesn't work and getting same error.

Comment: @RaviKChowdary did you change the parameter in eclipse.ini?

Comment: @Jhanvi :- where to change the parameter?

Comment: refer this: http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jst.j2ee.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Ftchangejavalevel.html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540548/how-do-i-get-eclipse-to-use-a-different-compiler-version-for-java