# How do I check which version of Eclipse Compiler am I using?

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-construction

I'm using Eclipse compiler for java. But how do I check the version number of the compiler?

Comment: But you can check by Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Compiler

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540548/how-do-i-get-eclipse-to-use-a-different-compiler-version-for-java

Comment: @OldProgrammer That's not correct. Eclipse contains its own compiler (The Eclipse Compiler for Java, ECJ, which is part of the JDT).

Answer (score 4):

Eclipse includes its own compiler for running and debugging code from within the IDE.  Its part of the [JDT Core](http://www.eclipse.org/jdt/core/) plugin and is based on the old [Visual Age for Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_VisualAge) compiler.

More info can be found in [this StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061654/what-is-the-difference-between-javac-and-the-eclipse-compiler) question.

You can check which version by going to Help->About Eclipse, finding the "Eclipse.org" tile:
[image: About Eclipse]

And click on it:

[image: JDT info]

Answer (score -1):

Go to Window > Preferences > Java > Compiler.

Snapshot

[image]