# spring MVC servlet mapping

Tags: spring-mvc

I am trying a sample spring MVC application. My web.xml has

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>        
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/test</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

so my question is how I can call my test controller if I just type in the url

```
   http://localhost:8080/MySpringProject/test
```

Where do i need to make change to call exactly this type of URL so that my test controller called. I don't know what I am asking is correct or not but my requirement is that I don't want to end my UrL with "/" or "test.htm".

Please help and thanks in advance

Comment: What controller?  All you have is a `DispatcherServlet`.

Comment: Hi skaffman, in controller I have mapping like @RequestMapping("/test"). Is this should work? I myself is confused

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You usually map your dispatcher servlet to `/`, and then you have controllers with `@RequestMapping("/foo/bar")`. But if you define a servlet with a more specific url, it will get picked up.

Comment: Hi Bozho, so if I have mapping like @RequestMapping("/test") in my controller then with this http://localhost:8080/MySpringProject/test  URL this should work?

Comment: According to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3878957/basic-spring-mvc-config-pagenotfound-using-internalresourceviewresolver, this will prevent one from hiding your view jsps in the WEB-INF/ folder. In your app, do you configure the InternalResourceViewResolver to point to a prefix in the "WEB-INF" folder.