# Spring PageNotFound and URLMapping in web.xml

Tags: url, spring-mvc, view, tomcat7, web.xml

I have been reading a lot of questions like this, but I'm not getting out of the trouble, and I'm starting to think that the problem is tomcat playing around.
First of all, here are my web.xml, my *-servlet.xml and my controller.

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">

<display-name>Spring REST Server</display-name>
<description>Spring REST Server</description>
<context-param>
  <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>classpath:env/log4j.properties</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>
            classpath:config/applicationContext.xml
            classpath:config/kimboo-servlet.xml
</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
  <param-name>webAppRootKey</param-name>
  <param-value>Kimboo</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet -->
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>kimboo</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
      classpath:config/applicationContext.xml
      classpath:config/kimboo-servlet.xml
    </param-value>
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>kimboo</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/home/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

This is my kimboo-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="ar.com.kimboo.server.ui.controller" />

<mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/AppClient/pages/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
</bean>
```

And this is my controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/home")
public class HomeController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public String home() {
    return "login";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/main")
public String main() {
    return "main";
}

    @RequestMapping(value = "/about")
public String main() {
    return "about";
}
}
```

This is a pretty simple example, I don't know why isn't working. I have readed a lot of questions like this, here and in another sites, I don't know what I'm missing.

By the way, in the controller I tried all the convinations to match the url; put "/home/" or "home/" at the class level, and put "login" or "main" at method level.

The only thing that works is when I hit localhost:8080/myServer/home/. I tried using "/home/*" in the url-pattern of the web.xml instead "/home/". I also tried use "/" and "/*", but is the same.

The only way that this works is when in the url-pattern of the web.xml I use

```
<url-pattern>/home/</url-pattern>
<url-pattern>/home/main/</url-pattern>
<url-pattern>/home/login/</url-pattern>
```

Then I can hit all the url's. I don't know what to do, maybe this is a tomcat 7 problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you were not configured mapping for controller and annotation handler.Add this below bean configuration in the  kimboo-servlet.xml and also add the respective jars.It may work.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" />
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter" />

<bean id="simpleUrlMapping"  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="mappings">
         <value>
            /home/**=homeController 
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: This didn't work, I tried several times, with configurations like this, It's really annoying because in the log I'm actually seeing the mapped urls like `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping  - Mapped URL path [/home/main] onto handler 'homeControlle` `Mapped URL path [/home/main/] onto handler 'homeController'` and the controller bean `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  - Mapped URL path [/home/**] onto handler 'homeController'` but when I hit `http://localhost:8080/server/home/main` shows me in the log `No mapping found ... with URI [/server/home/main] in ... 'kimboo'`

Comment: I don't know why it is not working for you.Change web.xml url pattern like .<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>. but I'm not sure about this.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than this being a TomCat problem I suspect this is a problem with how you have annotated the controller. Please replace your controller annotations as follows

```
  @Controller
public class HomeController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/home")
public String home() {
    return "login";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/home/main")
public String main() {
    return "main";
}

    @RequestMapping(value = "home/about")
public String main() {
    return "about";
}

}
```

This is only a guess. Sorry if I got it wrong. I remember seeing this problem in REST services. Maybe its the same.Dont have time to test it myself now.

Comment: Sorry, I think thats is another kind of error, because, with your mapping or the mine I keep seeing the same mappings in the console, like `Mapped URL path [/home/main] onto handler 'homeController'` and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Look at this question: [Basic Spring MVC config: PageNotFound using InternalResourceViewResolver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3878957/basic-spring-mvc-config-pagenotfound-using-internalresourceviewresolver). The reason is your mapping which is too wide and interfere to `JspServlet` mapping.