# spring no mapping found for http request

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine

So I am getting this error when I upload to `google app engine` but when I build and run it locally everything works.

I am getting this error

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound:
No mapping found for HTTP request with URI
 [/api/default/_admin/task/createAppDomain] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring-dispatcher'
```

Here is the relevant portion of my `web.xml`

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I'm not sure how to fix this or go about debugging it considering it works locally but just not on the production server when I upload to google app engine.

Comment: I think this answer car help you : http://stackoverflow.com/a/3879544/4017037

Comment: @Tyler Rice try with this `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>` or `<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>`

Answer (score 0):

The error itself is self descriptive, however, I was facing a tricky case and I was getting the same error:

1. If you are using a windows machine locally, and it works there
2. Your jsp file has upper case letter in it (example: /pages/secure/my**P**age.jsp)
3. In your controller, you have something like:

**Controller:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String save(@Valid @ModelAttribute("form") Form form, BindingResult result) {

// Your code here

return "secure/mypage";
}
```

In this case, you won't be getting any errors locally because your operating system can find it, but I believe Google is not using windows, maybe Linux or whatever, in which the letter casing matters.