# How to work around the automatic cutting of the overflown content in overflow: auto?

Tags: html, css

I have an absolute positioned div inside an `overflow: auto`, as here:

[image]

There 5 row divs with position relative, and I have a `.grayBlock` inside the row 2 div.

As you can see, the gray block is cut off due to the `overflow: auto`.

I want it to escape the container. What can I do?

Comment: Codepen is here: https://codepen.io/owlran/pen/jwozwX

Comment: By removing position from `.canvasInfo__block` maybe?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The `overflow` is only very badly configurable, it is a dirty side of the css. You likely can't do this without javascript (what is even dirtier).

Comment: I saved your question! I saved it! :-) It had been surely closed, nobody had wanted to decode it. But I did! I did!

Comment: Thanks @peterh for your help !

Comment: My pleasure :-) If an answer solved your problem, you can accept it by clicking the pipe icon to the left of the answer. It is a reward the answerer, and helps others to know that the problem is already solved. There are additional rewarding/motivating possibilities, the triangles up and down to the "0", also on the left side of the answer. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct an additional `canvasInfo__block` around the current one. It should be a little bit wider as the internal block (in my example, `canvasInfo__block2`).

The `overflow: auto` will surely cut, you can't do anything with it, *but* it won't be very bad because it is enough wide, to contain the internal `canvasInfo__block2` and also the gray block overflowing from it.

`canvasInfo__block2` needs an `overflow: visible`, while the external `canvasInfo__block` can get its `overflow: auto`.

The result:

[image]

HTML:

```
.canvasInfo
  .canvasInfo__title 
    h3 Title
  .hr
  .canvasInfo__block
    .canvasInfo__block2
      .canvasInfo__slider sliderBar
      .canvasInfo__activity Motion activity
      .row
        .circle
          span line1
      .row
        .circle
          span line2
        .grayBlock hi2
      .row
        .circle
          span line3
      .row
        .circle
          span line4
      .row
        .circle
          span line5
```

CSS:

```
.canvasInfo {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 500px;
}

.hr {
  margin: 10px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;  
}

.canvasInfo__block {
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 400px;
  height: 120px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.canvasInfo__block2 {
  position: relative;
  overflow: visible;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.grayBlock {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: gray;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: -20px;
  z-index: -1;
}
.row {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  position: relative;
}
.circle
{
  position: relative;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 60px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #000;
  span {
    margin-left: 20px;
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems that  `overflow: visible;` is not necessary in the `.canvasInfo__block2 `. I removed it from css and got the same result as yours. The only solution to this is put the wider div surround it ?

Comment: @Wei-ChengChen `overflow: visible` is not necessary because it is the default setting. I put it onto only for better readibility. | If you give a negative margin or border to the outer div, you can likely "eat" that empty space on the left side without cutting anything (note, margins have meaning only in relative/static position).