# Spring MVC dispatcher servlet, URIs without the application name

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

I am trying to reach my controller:

```
package com.atmWebApp.controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class FirstController {

        @RequestMapping("/welcome/")
        public ModelAndView helloWorld() {

            String message = "<br><div align='center'>" + "<h1>Hello World, Spring 3.2.1 Example by Crunchify.com<h1> <br>";
            message += "<a href='http://crunchify.com/category/java-web-development-tutorial/'>More Examples</a>";
            return new ModelAndView("welcome", "message", message);
        }

        @RequestMapping("/")
        public ModelAndView helloWorld1() {

            String message = "<br><div align='center'>" + "<h1>Hello World, Spring 3.2.1 Example by Crunchify.com<h1> <br>";
            message += "<a href='http://crunchify.com/category/java-web-development-tutorial/'>More Examples</a>";
            return new ModelAndView("welcome", "message", message);
        }
}
```

app-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd

http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 

http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan
        base-package="com.atmWebApp.controllers" />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>AtmWebApp</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>app</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>app</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>AtmWebApp</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>app</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>app</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**Specifically, I would like to start my server and have my root be at localhost:8080/, but I can't even seem to hit FirstController. So my main question is: why am I not hitting either method in FirstController?**

I believe that my issue is in the app-server.xml or web.xml files. I have looked through stack overflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18683847/no-mapping-found-for-http-request-with-uri-in-dispatcherservlet-with-name), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098969/spring-dispatcherservlet-no-mapping-found-for-http-request), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11692837/url-mapping-issue-spring-web-mvc), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8848724/no-mapping-found-for-http-request-with-uri-myproject-in-dispatcherservlet-wi), but am at a loss as to what I am doing differently than these folks.

Any help?

Comment: localhost:8080/ would be your ROOT.war

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/715506/tomcat-6-how-to-change-the-root-application

Answer (score 1):

From what I know you should have a `@RequestMapping(..)` on the **Controller** also. Hence you should have something like this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class FirstController {
    ...
```

As well you can check also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16988689/spring-mvc-configure-url-pattern) response for URL mappings.

Answer (score 1):

In the web.xml file,under the servlet mapping try changing the Url-Pattern from   / to   /*.