# Spring configuration not finding with Configured name

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

The  following are my configuration file  i configured

> WEB-INF/classes/applicationContext.xml but it searching for 
>   WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="starter_anil" version="2.4" 
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Anil-Spring</display-name>
    <!-- Servlets -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>WEB-INF/classes/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- Listeners -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

i am getting following exception

```
EVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
```

here is my applicationContext

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">

<beans>
    <import resource="config/controllers.xml" />
    <!-- <import resource="conf/spring/services.xml" />
    <import resource="conf/spring/persistence.xml" />
    <import resource="conf/spring/daos.xml" />
    <import resource="conf/spring//interceptors.xml" /> -->
</beans>
```

the solution for this is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="starter_anil" version="2.4" 
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Anil-Spring</display-name>
    <!-- Servlets -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
        </init-param> 
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Listeners -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

> WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI
>   [/AnilsSpring/WEB-INF/jsp/hello.jsp] in DispatcherServlet with name
>   'mvc-dispatcher'
>   please guide line me once

Comment: Put your `applicationContext.xml` under `WEB-INF`

Comment: WEB-INF/classes/applicationContext.xml why it not taking that configuration

Comment: Because Spring looks for it, by default, under `WEB-INF`. Or do what Majid has posted, but that is bad practice, because it doesn't belong there.

Comment: contextConfigLocation i useed for configuration file

Answer (score 1):

Why is your `applicationContext` is in the classes? Move it to the WEB-INF directory, as it is told in the comment. That should fix the problem.

The /classes directory is for the compiled classes, but not for the configuration files.

Comment: leave it for ideals tell me why contextConfigLocation looking for another path

Comment: Because the default lookup path is the /WEB-INF directory.

Comment: did u know  need of  contextConfigLocation  in spring mvc

Comment: I'm sorry, but that is a bit weird question. There are several comments that point you the reason of the problem and the good-practice programming issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `/` in `/WEB-INF/classes/applicationContext.xml`

If it still doesn't work, try adding this instead in your `web.xml` (before the servlet declaration)

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/classes/applicationContext.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]  i got this to avoid that only i configured above init param

Comment: why it is serching /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml eventhogh in configured context config location

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app id="starter_anil" version="2.4" 
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Anil-Spring</display-name>
        <!-- Servlets -->
   <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
       </init-param> 
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>



    <!-- Listeners -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>





</web-app>
```

this made exception less start on tomcat but i am little bit confused

Answer (score 0):

If that's where you absolutely must have it, try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="starter_anil" version="2.4" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Anil-Spring</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value> 
    </context-param>

    <the-rest-of-your-stuff />
</web-app>
```

You might need a `/` before `applicationContext.xml`, but I don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to do undeploy. and deploy it. it will work . .
it works for me for the exception
IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/spring application config.xml];

Answer (score -1):

> WEB-INF/classes/applicationContext.xml for this requirement, you have to put applicationContext.xml in class path i.e.

If you are using maven then put it in src/main/resources folder, otherwise put in the src folder.

Then you will find it inside WEB-INF/classes

Comment: yes i am using maven it is inside src/main/resources folder only

Comment: why it is serching /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml eventhogh in configured context config location – ravula's just now edit

Comment: web.xml configuration see here  https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-webflow-samples/blob/master/webflow-showcase/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml

Comment: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/AnilsSpring/WEB-INF/jsp/hello.jsp] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher' can u tell me why it throws like that

Comment: you can check here for configuration http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/spring-mvc-tutorials/

Comment: hi i build my application from that example see once [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13524215/warning-no-mapping-found-for-http-request-with-uri-projectdemo-web-inf-jsp-re) he also got the same problem