# @RequestMapping not working for .jsp

Tags: spring

here is the url-pattern in web.xml

```
<servlet-mapping>  
<servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>  
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>  
</servlet-mapping>
```

Here is my controller

```
@Controller  
public class HelloController   
{  
        @RequestMapping("/*.km")  
    public String handleKm()  
    {  
        System.out.println("km ext called");  
        return "aaa";  
    }  

    @RequestMapping("/*.jsp")  
    public String handleJsp()  
    {  
        System.out.println("jsp pages called");  
        return "bbb";  
    }  
}
```

while accessing the url with /requestMapping/a.km , it is works, calls the handleKm() method.but with /requestMapping/a.jsp , it should call handleJsp().but it does not work. result : HTTP Status 404 - /requestMapping/a.jsp.
why ??

If I chane the url-pattern from "/" to "/*" , although both method are called , but dont get to the appropriate pages.
May be the "org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" is not working .

Comment: Where did "requestMappingExperiment" come from versus "requestMapping"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [No mapping found for HTTP request with URI \[/WEB-INF/pages/apiForm.jsp\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266303/no-mapping-found-for-http-request-with-uri-web-inf-pages-apiform-jsp)

Comment: sorry, that was requestMapping actually

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this related SO post (possibly a duplicate)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266303/no-mapping-found-for-http-request-with-uri-web-inf-pages-apiform-jsp).  I think the `.jsp` extension is confusing the dispatcher servlet.  Try using an extension that isn't `.jsp` and see if that works.