# Error: WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request WARNING: No mapping found for HTTPrequest with URI. Help me?

Tags: spring, jetty

I have a problem with my project. When i browser `http://localhost:8080/user/form` to display UserForm then occur following error:

> WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/user/form] in
>   DispatcherSe rvlet with name 'userservice'

Here file `userservice-servlet.xml`

```
<beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd ">
    <context:component-scan base-package="edu.java.spring.service.user.controller"></context:component-scan>
    <context:component-scan base-package="edu.java.spring.service.user.dao"></context:component-scan>
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="order" value="1" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/user/" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>

        </property>
        <property name="mappingLocations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:User.hbm.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>

        <property name="packagesToScan" value="edu.java.spring.service.user.model" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="transactionManager"  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver" />
        <property name="url"
            value="jdbc:derby:D:\PROJECTSPRING\userdb;create=true" />
        <property name="username" value="" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView">
        <property name="contentType" value="text/plain"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Here file `UserRestServiceController.java`

```
@Controller
public class UserRestServiceController {
    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;
    @Autowired
    private View jsonView;
    @RequestMapping(value="/user/form,",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView user(){
//      System.out.println("anh yeu em ");
        return new ModelAndView("UserForm","User",new User());
    }
    @RequestMapping(value="/user/json/{username}")
    public ModelAndView loadUser(@PathVariable("username")String name){
        return new ModelAndView(jsonView,"data",userDao.loadUser(name));
    }


}
```

Here `file web.xml`

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
          version="3.0">
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>userservice</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>userservice</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>userservice</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            edu.java.spring.service.user.controller.CustomContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/userservice-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
</web-app>
```

Comment: possible copy of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266303/no-mapping-found-for-http-request-with-uri-web-inf-pages-apiform-jsp

Comment: JavaClazzWeb-servlet.xml is "userservice-servlet.xml"?

Comment: @Sanj, i have edited, but i have same error

Comment: Can you check if /user/UserForm.jsp exists?

Comment: @Sanj file UserForm.jsp have exist, i still haven't solved this problem

Comment: change userservice url-pattern to "/" instead of "/*"

Comment: I have finded way to solove this problem. `value /use/form,` odd a comma, so not mapping

Answer (score 0):

```
<property name="prefix" value="/user/" />
```

This means you have kept your JSPs inside webapp/user directory?

Try to move inside WEB-INF and check.

```
<property name="prefix">
   <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
</property>
```