# Bootstrap and CSS formatting not showing JSP

Tags: java, css, spring

I created a JSP file. Earlier, it was an html file and the bootstrap was showing perfectly. Now, I changed it to a jsp file. So, when the user enters the URL, it routes via the Dispatcher Servlet and then the user see the jsp.
For some reason, the CSS formatting is not showing:

I am trying to display ipay.jsp:
Here is the file structure[image]

The Servlet that maps to this JSP:

```
package com.tests;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

/*
 * author: Crunchify.com
 * 
 */

@Controller
public class CrunchifyHelloWorld {

    @RequestMapping("/welcome1")
    public ModelAndView helloWorld() {

        String message = "HELLO HEY";
        System.out.println("dpay");
        return new ModelAndView("ipay", "message", message);
    }
}
```

I changed the structure and code to as follows, still not working[image]

HEre is my servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.stellar,com.tests" />



    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Here is my web.xml:

```
<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

   <servlet>
        <servlet-name>stellar</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>stellar</servlet-name>

        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>



</web-app>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy your default.css under resources folder.

Then add resources mapping in your stellar-servlet.xml under beans tag.

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

The folder structure and url-mapping are completely different things in spring framework. Spring mvc has a urlBasedviewResolver to resolve jsps with JstlView.

Answer (score 2):

Again trouble with path. Your `default.css` is under `jsp` folder.

Either change the href to `jsp\default.css` or move the `default.css` level up.

I would recommend to create a separate `css` folder and place all the *.css files there. Also adapt your path.

In general WEB-INF is your root. Start paths from there and place your files accordingly.

Comment: I changed it to     <link href="/WEB-INF/jsp/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">, still does not display

Comment: Should be `<link href="jsp/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`. WEB-INF is root no need to mention it

Comment: Still not working. Updated the post with new directory structure. I did notice this message in the logs: org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound

Comment: `No mapping found` means spring tries to find a controller to process the URL. Try to add `<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>` to your `stellar-servlet.xml` and check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266303/no-mapping-found-for-http-request-with-uri-web-inf-pages-apiform-jsp

Comment: I have added both my servlet.xml and web.xml to the question. Are you certain I should add mvc:default-servlet-handler if I have annotativation driven already

Comment: No, you should not. I just cannot see your servlet.xml

Comment: You excluded resources only `<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />` but your jsp is not under resources.