# I am getting error in spriing No mapping found for HTTP request with URI

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jsp, servlets

I am getting error in spriing No mapping found for HTTP request with URI

I know this question already have been asked, but for my error I referred those question even I did not got the solution for my error.

Error log

```
 Jul 08, 2018 4:30:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'project'
    Jul 08, 2018 4:30:51 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet initServletBean
    INFO: FrameworkServlet 'project': initialization started
    Jul 08, 2018 4:30:51 PM org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext prepareRefresh
    INFO: Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'project-servlet': startup date [Sun Jul 08 16:30:51 IST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
    Jul 08, 2018 4:30:51 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
    INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/project-servlet.xml]
    Jul 08, 2018 4:30:52 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
    INFO: Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler 'org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler#0'
    Jul 08, 2018 4:30:52 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet initServletBean
    INFO: FrameworkServlet 'project': initialization completed in 806 ms
```

I am just trying to display Hello World from Controller.java when I clicked submit button from index.jsp

```
Error : 
Jul 08, 2018 2:28:36 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/project/myMethod] in DispatcherServlet with name 'project'

Web Pages/index.jsp:

<html>
<body>

<form action="myMethod">
Username : <input name="un"><br/>
Password :&nbsp;&nbsp;<input name="pwd"><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>

</body>
</html>

Under
src/main/resources
com.project
Controll.java

package com.project;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class Controll {

    @RequestMapping("/myMethod")
    public void CtrlMethod() {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }

}

web.xml

<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >
<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>  
  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>project</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>project</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
 </web-app>


 project-servlet.xml

 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd ">
    <context:annotation-config /> 
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.project"/>

</beans>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No mapping found for HTTP request with URI \[/WEB-INF/pages/apiForm.jsp\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266303/no-mapping-found-for-http-request-with-uri-web-inf-pages-apiform-jsp)

Comment: What changes I need to do?

Comment: apparently you're missing `<mvc:annotation-driven />` in `project-servlet.xml`

Comment: NO still the same error showing: WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/project/myMethod] in DispatcherServlet with name 'project'

Comment: Now there is no error but I cant find Hello World Message pls help

Comment: Hi benjamin, I have updated the error log which I am getting. In my Question Itself please check.

Comment: what the log says after you click on submit button ?

Comment: in the console that is the message which i have pasted in the questtion I cant see helo world anywhere

Comment: are you getting hello world? in console

Comment: for me that is the log showing.... i will mention the project link  bellow could  you pls check

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=170S3mi04bC-okzhUaENZzC7g15W8NQZl

Comment: pls check and tell me what is the issue

Comment: It is not controller.java it is controll.java  Inside java Resource-src/main/resource 
 Under This
 com.project
 Control

Comment: Pls check and let me know I am waiting

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174593/discussion-between-vytcdc-and-benjamin-c).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems in your `web.xml` you did not write

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/project-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```